# Share website url on whats app using android studio

Tags: android, whatsapp

I have tried following for sharing website url on whatsapp. I got error of please try again. I refers the code from  http://techzog.com/development/android-share-to-whatsapp-code-for-developers/ Dose anyone know how do i do that?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText message;
     Button btn;
    ImageView img;
    Uri uri;
    String imgurl="http://www.google.com";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      uri = Uri.parse(""+imgurl);
        //Caption for the image!
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caption);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageToBeShared);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                                       try {

                                           Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                           waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                           String text = "Want to share this";

                                           PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                                           //Check if package exists or not. If not then code
                                           //in catch block will be called
                                           waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                                           waIntent.putExtra(waIntent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                                           waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                                           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

                                       } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                   .show();
                                       }

                                   }
                               }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have the code, what is the problem ?

Comment: problem is i am not able to share the parameters passed in uri. link is not reflecting on whatsapp

Comment: `link is not reflecting on whatsapp` you do not have any `link` in your intent

Comment: Just include the URL in the text extra. WhatApp will parse and linkify it.

Comment: do i need to add waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, imgurl);

Comment: do you fixed it..?

Comment: refer my answer below..@ashwinishahasane

Answer (score 4):

Try this to share your url in whatsapp.

For better usage define a function for sharing in whatsapp like below.

```
void shareinWhatsapp(String shareURL) {
        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        if (waIntent != null) {
            waIntent.putExtra(
                    Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    shareURL);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
    }
```

Then call the function whenever the share on whatsapp button is clicked. Do as like below..

```
whatsapp_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                shareinWhatsapp();
            }
        });
```

Hope this will work for you.. Kindly try this..